# Switch : Input remained in console (I've asked this questions several times but no one seems to know why)

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

[image]

Please let me describe the problem verbally first.

What you see on the console is what the problem is.

The coding is done with Scanner and switch-statement.

1. It asks to User, to who do you want to give MP portion. (each character's MP max is 30)
2. I wanted to test and tried 2,3,2,4 inputs to see what it would say, and as you could see, it says, "Jongwoo's MP is full. Choose different Character.." and so does for all other characters as expected, except for Kyungseok, who's MP is currently 15. So when I input 1 (for Kyungseok) it says Kyungseok's MP is healed , and all of sudden the rest character does the same thing. (please ignore the amount of it healed, I need to fix that)

**One thing I realized was that they were printed in the order that I put in numbers to test : 2, 3, 2, 4.
So the input remained in the console became input and the switch-statement takes it as an input.**

I don't know why it does that. 
I have a lot of switch-statements, and it is not the only switch-statement having this problem. and the following code is the code for the switch-statement.

```
    public static void chooseMMCha1(Character member) {
    boolean wrongAnswer;
    do {
        wrongAnswer = false;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            sc.next();
        }

    switch (sc.nextInt())  {
    case 1:
        chooseMMCha(chosenMember[0], member);
        break;
    case 2:
        chooseMMCha(chosenMember[1], member);
        break;
    case 3:
        chooseMMCha(chosenMember[2], member);
        break;
    case 4:
        chooseMMCha(chosenMember[3], member);
        break;
    case 5:
        chooseMMCha(chosenMember[4], member);
        break;
    case 6:
        turn(member);
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("From 1 to 6");
        wrongAnswer = true;
        break;

    }
    }while(wrongAnswer);
}
```

Comment: Consider changing sc.next() to sc.nextInt() and also padding all of your nextInts with nextLine

Comment: I think you need a `return` inside the if currentMp==maxMp

Comment: What is the `chooseMMCha()` method?

Comment: @GBlodgett it's in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what you have here is unintended recursion.

In your `chooseMMCha1()` method you call `chooseMMCha()`. 
This method then checks to see if the selection is valid. If it isn't then it calls `chooseMMCha1()` again.

However once you input a valid input the call to `chooseMMCha1()` will come off the stack and it will return to your call to `chooseMMCha()`. Once it returns to here you print out that the character was healed. Thus once you input a valid input, all the invalid inputs that you pushed onto the stack will resolve and your method will print out that they have been healed.

In the case of an invalid input you need to put a `return;` statement after your call to `chooseMMCha1()` to make sure that you don't continue with the method once the invalid inputs come off the stack:

```
if(chosenMember.getMP() == chosenMember.getMaxMP()) {
    System.out.println(chosenMember +"'s MP is already full");
    chooseMMCha1(member);
    return; //Exit the method
}
```

Comment: God thank you sooooooo much !!
I completely forgot to put Return when I want it to exit the method in every if-statement............ 
really appreciate it !! :))